# Get notified when new connection is established with server

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, lidgren

I am using the [Lidgren library](https://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) in order to communicate strings throw computers over network. I can get notified when a client disconnects from the server but I can not when a client connects. I tried this piece of code running in a different thread :

```
 static void connectionCheck()
    {
        if (server.ConnectionsCount != con)
        {

            for (int i = con; i < s_server.Connections.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(server.Connections[i].Peer.Configuration.LocalAddress.ToString() + " connected");
            }
            con = server.ConnectionsCount;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        connectionCheck();
    }
```

where `con` is the old number of connections. The only output I get is `0.0.0.0 connected` after the newly connected client sends a message. Why isn't this working and how can I get notified when a new connection is established?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call ReadMessage() on s_server; when you receive a message of type StatusChanged, examine the first byte, it holds a NetConnectionStatus enum - if it's "Connected" then a remote peer just established a connection to this peer.